# Execute merge query in Spring JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a couple SQL tables say

```
table1
___________________________ _ _ _ _ _
|id | date | col1 | col2 |col3 |col4 ...
--------------------------------------
|1  | 1/11 |      |      |     | 
____________________________ _ _ _ _ _
```

and

```
table2
_________________________
|id | date | col1 | col2 |
--------------------------
|1  | 1/11 | ice  | cone |
```

I want the ability to merge data from table2 into table1 based on the id and date - if the id and date match - then the data (col1 and col2) is copied over from table2 onto table1.

I have the SQL query to make this work

```
// merge_query1:

MERGE table1 t1
USING table2 t2
ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date=t2.date )
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET
                    t1.col1 = t2.col1,
                    t1.col2 = t2.col2
;
```

now the question is how do I execute this using Spring JPA.

I was thinking something along the lines of writing a JPA Interface like so.

```
// How would I design this or something like this ? 
// What pojo should be put instead of the question mark in JpaRepository<?, .. >

public interface MergeTables extends JpaRepository<?, Long> {
    @Query(value = MERGE_TABLE2_WITH_TABLE1, nativeQuery = true)
    void executeMergeTableQuery();
}
```

where the `MERGE_TABLE2_WITH_TABLE1` String is

```
public static String MERGE_TABLE2_WITH_TABLE1 = "MERGE table1 t1
                                                   USING table2 t2
                                                   ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date=t2.date )
                                                   WHEN MATCHED
                                                   THEN UPDATE SET
                                                         t1.col1 = t2.col1,
                                                         t1.col2 = t2.col2
                                                   ;
                                                ";
```

So the question is
How would I design so that the merge query is executed upon calling the above function or is there another way of doing something like this?

Comment: Doesn't it work if you add `@Modifying` to `executeMergeTableQuery`? See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation

Comment: that did it - adding `@Modifying` and `@Transactional` made it work.
thank you @Davide D'Alto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding
`@Modified` and `@Transactional` did the trick.